Is there a software tool, payment or free that can transcribe live meetings from system audio and not just mp4 files
Is there a software that can do this live and could differentiate the voices, so those would get described as Person1 Person2, with timestamp and what they're saying.

What platform is this for?

MacOS, @RohitGupta

https://Otter.ai
Otter has had automatic transcription with multiple speaker identities for a few years.

Import an audio or video file
Audio formats

AAC (listed in the Finder with the .m4p filename extension)
MP3
M4A (including Apple voice memos)
WAV
WMA
OGG



but Otter can only do this with a Audio file and not live system audio.


Otter is primarily for real-time transcription. So, if "live system audio" means "real time," then Otter can do it.
In the contrasting phrase "from system audio and not just mp4 files," mp4 is a container that implies a narrow range of audio codecs. Otter processes file codecs other than mp4-compatible codecs.

